# Using d3 with force-graph in Vue

Tags: vue.js, d3.js

I am using force-graph in Vue. force-graph has been installed using npm and ForceGraph is imported into a single-file vue component. When I use for a ForceGraph Graph

```
Graph.d3Force("link",d3.forceLink())
```

I get an error that d3 is undefined. I have tried to install d3 and to import d3 from it without success.

I am aware of vue-force-graph, but that is reported to have high vulnerability and using it gives errors on multiple imports of threejs.

Answer (score 0):

The errors vanished when I defined d3 as

```
var d3 = require("d3")
```